# Searching for term within an array

Tags: arrays, perl, parsing, search, grep

I am parsing a very simple text file and manipulating it into an array. In my last step of the program I am trying to search for a user given term. I have tried many things but cannot seem to get it to work, my I search for a term that I know for a fact is in the array it still does not find it. I have a hunch that the variables might get tinkered with sometime during the "split", "chop", and "sort" functions but I am not exactly sure.

```
print "\n";
print "Enter a term you would like to search for: \n";

my $element = <STDIN>;

$num = grep(/$element/,@final);

if($num > 0){
print ("Term: " . $element . " found " . $num . " times. \n");
}else{
print "Not found. \n";
}
```

So I know for a fact that the term "apple" is in the list, when I search the term "apple" it prints that it was not found. Help please!!

Comment: Is the user search term intended to be a regex?  Shell-like pattern?  Literal string match?  Case sensitive?

Comment: Just `chomp()` the `$element`. It's got a newline at the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try

```
chomp(my $element = <STDIN>);
```

Because your standard input will have a trailing newline that otherwise gets matched in your search. E.g.:

```
$element = "foo\n";   
grep /$element/, "foo bar";  # will not match
```

You should also be aware that meta characters will be interpreted in your input. So for example, `foo?` will be considered "fo followed by an optional o". To avoid that you can use `quotemeta` or `\Q ... \E`, e.g. in your regex use:

```
/\Q$element\E/
```

Comment: Your response was extremely helpful to me in understanding how to use the chomp function. However upon deep inspection i discovered that I was searching for the term outside of the scope in which the array was declared. After moving a few curly braces the program was working perfectly. I was programing in command line and it was extremely hard to manage the formatting, which is why the problem occurred. I am use to programming java in netBeans which will format it for me. Again, thanks for you response, i did implement chomp in to my code so i greatly appreciate it!

Comment: I believe netBeans has a perl plugin. You're welcome. If you feel the answer helped, you can accept it by clicking the check mark.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this :

```
use Data::Dumper;

my @final = <DATA>;
chomp(@final);
print Dumper \@final;

print "Enter a term you would like to search for >>> ";
chomp(my $element = <STDIN>);

$num = grep { /$element/ } @final;

if ($num > 0){
    print("Term: $element found $num times\n");
}
else{
    print("Not found. \n");
}


__DATA__
foo
bar
base
```

**NOTE**

- if you don't `chomp()`, you are trying to grep `element\n` instead of `element`
- `Data::Dumper` is a great module to display any data (structures or not).

Comment: Your response was extremely helpful to me in understanding how to use the chomp function. However upon deep inspection i discovered that I was searching for the term outside of the scope in which the array was declared. After moving a few curly braces the program was working perfectly. I was programing in command line and it was extremely hard to manage the formatting, which is why the problem occurred. I am use to programming java in netBeans which will format it for me. Again, thanks for you response, i did implement chomp in to my code so i greatly appreciate it!